# Arrow functions in closures

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

Why this is working:

```
var a = () => { 

    var print = function(i) { console.log(i); return this; }    
    var print2 = function(i) { console.log(i); return this; }

    return { print:print , print2:print2 }
}

a().print(5).print2(5);
```

this is also working:

```
var b = () => { 

    var print = (i) => { console.log(i); return this; }    
    return { print:print}
}
b().print('Arrow function works');
```

while this is not working:

```
var b = () => { 

    var print = (i) => { console.log(i); return this; }    
    var print2 = function(i) { console.log(i); return this; }

    return { print:print , print2:print2 }
}
b().print(5).print2(5);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/1gt2kxfh/14/

Comment: Because that's how arrow functions work (and indeed is the main reason for why they were introduced - contrary to popular belief, it's nothing to do with saving keystrokes). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this, amongst others

Comment: I updated the question with a new working example.

Comment: In the print function constructed with an arrow syntax the `this` references the scope of `b`. While in the function declaration `this` refers to it's own scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's all due to arrow functions behavior([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions))

Step by step explanation:

```js
var b = () => { 
    // 1
    var print = (i) => { console.log(i); return this; }    
    var print2 = function(i) { console.log(i); return this; }

    return { print:print , print2:print2 }
}
const res = b()
// 2
const secondRes = res.print(5)
// 3
secondRes.print2(5);
```

1. here `print` function saves `this` reference from the outer scope, so `this` can't be reassigned anymore
2. now `print` function is not using `this` reference that comes from `res` variable, because `this` has already been attached to `print` function above
3. as a result `secondRes` is not going to reference to the object that was returned by `b` function. But it will use `this` reference that is attached to `print` function. And finally because `secondRes` doesn't have `print2` property - it throws

Hope it helps <3

Comment: I add to read your answer several times, but yeahhh got it. It's clear now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In a non-arrow function, the value of `this` depends on how the function is called. If the function is called as a member of an object, `this` refers to this object:

```
someObj.myFunction() // inside myFunction this will point to someObj
```

In contrast, the arrow functions do not affect `this`. So whithin an arrow function the value of `this` is whatever it is in the enclosing scope.

Comment: Why if I add `var self=this` it still does not work? https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/1gt2kxfh/20/

Comment: Then it will still not return the functions from `b`.

Comment: @Fifi Good question. In the first example the `this` inside the print functions refers to the object generated in the return statement: `return { print:print , print2:print2 }` When you try to preserve `this` by assigning it to some other variable (you don't say exactly where), it is not pointing to this object but to some other function around the assignment statement.

Comment: self is a local variable of c. Not easy to explain, look at the following JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/1gt2kxfh/20/.

Answer (score 2):

The answer from [Lex82](https://stackoverflow.com/users/302793/lex82) gives the why. If you want to return the functions, you can use function chaining:

```js
var b = () => { 

    var print = (i) => { console.log(i); return { print:print , print2:print2 }; }    
    var print2 = function(i) { console.log(i); return this; }

    return { print:print , print2:print2 }
}
b().print(5).print2(5);
```